# Split Angular component unit test containing async

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, angular-components

I have a component, which loads some data from the server via a service, and displays it.

I have written the following test for the component (which works):

```
...
it('Should contains data after loading', async(() => {
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(element.querySelector('h1').textContent.trim()).toBe(expectedTitle);
        expect(element.querySelector('p').textContent.trim()).toBe(expectedParagraph);
        element.querySelectorAll('ul > li').forEach((li, index) => {
            expect(li.textContent.trim()).toBe(expectedListItem[index]);
        });
    });
}));
```

Is there any possibility to split all of the expects into separate `it` tests?

I would like to have something like this:

```
...
describe('Component contains data after loading', async(() => {
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();

        it('Should contain title', () => {
            expect(element.querySelector('h1').textContent.trim()).toBe(expectedTitle);
        });

        it('Should contain paragraph', () => {
            expect(element.querySelector('p').textContent.trim()).toBe(expectedParagraph);
        });

        it('Should contain list', () => {
            element.querySelectorAll('ul > li').forEach((li, index) => {
                expect(li.textContent.trim()).toBe(expectedListItem[index]);
            });
        });
    });
}));
```

But I get error `Argument of type '(done: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'` in the `describe` line.

**EDIT:**

Added `TestBed` setup.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    serviceMock = prepareServiceMock();
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
            TestComponent
        ],
        providers: [
            { provide: TestService, useValue: serviceMock }
        ]
    }).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
});
```

Comment: Where is your `TestBed` configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each test spec will be executed separately. So what you can do is call `fixture.detectChanges();` every time at the start of new spec.

```
it('Should contain title', async(() => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
  expect(element.querySelector('h1').textContent.trim()).toBe(expectedTitle);
 }
})); 

it('Should contain paragraph', async(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(element.querySelector('p').textContent.trim()).toBe(expectedParagraph);
    }
}));
```

Make sure that you create new Component every time.

```
beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
});
```

Comment: So there is no possibility to extract the `whenStable().then` code into a single common block?